# nuget.exe command line spec/pack

Tags: powershell, nuget, specifications, pack

I am using nuget.exe to programmatically package my app with powershell.

The powershell commands I am running are

```
C:\nuget.exe spec $appName
C:\nuget.exe pack TestApp.nuspec -Version $version
```

This correctly packs everything in the working directory into the nupkg file, and my binaries show up under "Package contents" correctly...however there are some concerns.

I am seeing these errors in the command window:

```
Issue: Remove sample nuspec values.
```

When I open the nupkg in the Nuget package explorer, I see the default tags/description/release notes...etc.

The issue is with the "Dependencies" - it is also including a SampleDependency (>= 1.0.0) which seems to cause issues later on in my pipeline.

Is there a way to blow away that sample dependency through the spec/pack via command line?

Thanks

Comment: same is happening when nuget.exe has been used from command prompt